# (libuv) kqueue(): Too many open files in system when trying to write a file in Node Js

Tags: node.js

When I use fs.appendFile to save a lot of records from the DB I get an error. Here is the code:

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM Messages LIMIT 10000';
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        connection.end();

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        fs.appendFile('somefile.json', '{"index" : {"_index" : "mymessages" , "_type" : "data" , "_id" : "'+rows[i].message_id+'"}} \n' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]) + '\n', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
            //console.log(err);
        });


    }

    console.log('Added: ' + rows.length);


});
```

The error:

```
node es.js (libuv) kqueue(): Too many open files in system (libuv) kqueue(): Too many open files in system /private/var/www/mail-listener/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
              ^ Error: write EBADF
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:681:26)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:700:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:625:40)
    at Console.log (console.js:55:16)
    at Query._callback (/private/var/www/mail-listener/es.js:114:11)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/private/var/www/mail-listener/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.appendFile()` attempts to reopen the file every time. Since you're using a synchronous loop to execute asynchronous commands (`appendFile()`), you're going to queue up a *lot* of attempts to open that file.

Look into opening a single [write stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) to the file outside of your `for` loop, and re-use that write stream instead of `appendFile`.

Here is an example:

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM Messages LIMIT 10000';
connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err)
        throw err; // may want to look into making this async as well.

    connection.end();

    // may need to use a flag to open this as append, if that is your intent
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('somefile.json');

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var msg = '{"index" : {"_index" : "mymessages" , "_type" : "data" , "_id" : "'+rows[i].message_id+'"}} \n' + JSON.stringify(rows[i]) + '\n';
        stream.write(msg); // not back-pressure sensitive, see link below
    }

    // all writes have been buffered at this point
    // note: they have not necessarily been *written* yet.
    // if necessary, you may want to look into properly
    // handling backpressure as well, since this won't do it.
    // see: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable

    stream.end();

    stream.on('finish', function() {
        // writes are all *actually* finished at this point.
        console.log('added: ' + rows.length);
    });
});
```

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Is this a good solutions for dumping n number of records? For example 10 million?

Comment: Absolutely. I had a hunch you would be working with really large data sets, and streams will be the best solution for that. You should definitely look into the back-pressure, though. And possibly into whatever mysql library you are using. They may already support streaming, which would be much better than loading 10,000 records into memory at a time. You would be able to take them, transform them, and write them back out as they come.